# How to rebuild hive metadata

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hbase, hdfs

I am using hive and hbase to do some analysis on data.
I accidently removed the following file in hdfs

```
 (hdfs)     /user/hive/mydata.db
```

Although all table are existing in hive but when I retrieve data from hive through thrift server to plot it , it shows nothing. How can I rebuild my data. Any guide etc.

Comment: Why not recreate your hive tables?

Comment: I created tables again but it show only data for current day. But actuallu I have data for about 3 months

Comment: Was it a partitioned table? Looks like it. If yes, then you will have to create a new table and insert overwrite the data into that table with dynamic partitioning.